# Issue in downloading android SDK tools & API specific sdks

Tags: android

I am using ubuntu 32 bit machine, running eclipse indigo 3.7 for my android application development.

on downloading android SDk's using Android SDK manager. am getting the URL fetching error

"Fetching URL: http://dl.htcdev.com/sdk/addon.xml" & stuck over there itself. It's not able to fetch other add-ons.

Can anyone help on this ASAP.

```
Fetching https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml
Validate XML
Parse XML
Fetched Add-ons List successfully
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-7.xml
Validate XML: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-7.xml
Parse XML:    https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-7.xml
  Found SDK Platform Android 1.1, API 2, revision 1 (Obsolete)
  Found SDK Platform Android 1.5, API 3, revision 4
  Found SDK Platform Android 1.6, API 4, revision 3
  Found SDK Platform Android 2.0, API 5, revision 1 (Obsolete)
  Found SDK Platform Android 2.0.1, API 6, revision 1 (Obsolete)
  Found SDK Platform Android 2.1, API 7, revision 3
  Found SDK Platform Android 2.2, API 8, revision 3
  Found SDK Platform Android 2.3.1, API 9, revision 2 (Obsolete)
  Found SDK Platform Android 2.3.3, API 10, revision 2
  Found SDK Platform Android 3.0, API 11, revision 2
  Found SDK Platform Android 3.1, API 12, revision 3
  Found SDK Platform Android 3.2, API 13, revision 1
  Found SDK Platform Android 4.0, API 14, revision 3
  Found SDK Platform Android 4.0.3, API 15, revision 3
  Found SDK Platform Android 4.1, API 16, revision 2
  Found ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 14, revision 2
  Found ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 15, revision 2
  Found ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 16, revision 2
  Found Samples for SDK API 7, revision 1
  Found Samples for SDK API 8, revision 1
  Found Samples for SDK API 9, revision 1 (Obsolete)
  Found Samples for SDK API 10, revision 1
  Found Samples for SDK API 11, revision 1
  Found Samples for SDK API 12, revision 1
  Found Samples for SDK API 13, revision 1
  Found Samples for SDK API 14, revision 2
  Found Samples for SDK API 15, revision 2
  Found Samples for SDK API 16, revision 1
  Found Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 14
  Found Android SDK Tools, revision 20.0.3
  Found Android SDK Tools, revision 21 rc3
  Found Documentation for Android SDK, API 16, revision 2
  Found Sources for Android SDK, API 14, revision 1
  Found Sources for Android SDK, API 15, revision 2
  Found Sources for Android SDK, API 16, revision 2
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addon.xml
Validate XML: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addon.xml
Parse XML:    https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addon.xml
  Found Google APIs, Android API 3, revision 3
  Found Google APIs, Android API 4, revision 2
  Found Google APIs, Android API 5, revision 1 (Obsolete)
  Found Google APIs, Android API 6, revision 1 (Obsolete)
  Found Google APIs, Android API 7, revision 1
  Found Google APIs, Android API 8, revision 2
  Found Google APIs, Android API 9, revision 2 (Obsolete)
  Found Google APIs, Android API 10, revision 2
  Found Google APIs, Android API 11, revision 1
  Found Google APIs, Android API 12, revision 1
  Found Google APIs, Android API 13, revision 1
  Found Google APIs, Android API 14, revision 2
  Found Google APIs, Android API 15, revision 2
  Found Google APIs, Android API 16, revision 2
  Found Google TV Addon, Android API 12, revision 2
  Found Android Support Library, revision 10
  Found Google Play Licensing Library, revision 2
  Found Google Play APK Expansion Library, revision 2
  Found Google USB Driver, revision 7
  Found Google Play Billing Library, revision 2
  Found Google AdMob Ads SDK, revision 7
  Found Google Analytics SDK, revision 2
  Found Google Web Driver, revision 2
  Found Google Cloud Messaging for Android Library, revision 3
Fetching URL: http://dl.htcdev.com/sdk/addon.xml
Fetching URL: http://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/android/addon.xml
Fetching URL: http://www.echobykyocera.com/download/echo_repository.xml
Fetching URL: http://developer.lgmobile.com/sdk/android/repository.xml
Fetching URL: http://android-sdk-addons.motodevupdate.com/addons.xml
Fetching URL: http://innovator.samsungmobile.com/android/repository/repository.xml
Fetching URL: http://developer.sonymobile.com/edk/android/repository.xml
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img.xml
Done loading packages.
Fetching https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml
Validate XML
Parse XML
Fetched Add-ons List successfully
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-7.xml
Validate XML: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-7.xml
Parse XML:    https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-7.xml
  Found SDK Platform Android 1.1, API 2, revision 1 (Obsolete)
  Found SDK Platform Android 1.5, API 3, revision 4
  Found SDK Platform Android 1.6, API 4, revision 3
  Found SDK Platform Android 2.0, API 5, revision 1 (Obsolete)
  Found SDK Platform Android 2.0.1, API 6, revision 1 (Obsolete)
  Found SDK Platform Android 2.1, API 7, revision 3
  Found SDK Platform Android 2.2, API 8, revision 3
  Found SDK Platform Android 2.3.1, API 9, revision 2 (Obsolete)
  Found SDK Platform Android 2.3.3, API 10, revision 2
  Found SDK Platform Android 3.0, API 11, revision 2
  Found SDK Platform Android 3.1, API 12, revision 3
  Found SDK Platform Android 3.2, API 13, revision 1
  Found SDK Platform Android 4.0, API 14, revision 3
  Found SDK Platform Android 4.0.3, API 15, revision 3
  Found SDK Platform Android 4.1, API 16, revision 2
  Found ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 14, revision 2
  Found ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 15, revision 2
  Found ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 16, revision 2
  Found Samples for SDK API 7, revision 1
  Found Samples for SDK API 8, revision 1
  Found Samples for SDK API 9, revision 1 (Obsolete)
  Found Samples for SDK API 10, revision 1
  Found Samples for SDK API 11, revision 1
  Found Samples for SDK API 12, revision 1
  Found Samples for SDK API 13, revision 1
  Found Samples for SDK API 14, revision 2
  Found Samples for SDK API 15, revision 2
  Found Samples for SDK API 16, revision 1
  Found Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 14
  Found Android SDK Tools, revision 20.0.3
  Found Android SDK Tools, revision 21 rc3
  Found Documentation for Android SDK, API 16, revision 2
  Found Sources for Android SDK, API 14, revision 1
  Found Sources for Android SDK, API 15, revision 2
  Found Sources for Android SDK, API 16, revision 2
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addon.xml
Validate XML: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addon.xml
Parse XML:    https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addon.xml
  Found Google APIs, Android API 3, revision 3
  Found Google APIs, Android API 4, revision 2
  Found Google APIs, Android API 5, revision 1 (Obsolete)
  Found Google APIs, Android API 6, revision 1 (Obsolete)
  Found Google APIs, Android API 7, revision 1
  Found Google APIs, Android API 8, revision 2
  Found Google APIs, Android API 9, revision 2 (Obsolete)
  Found Google APIs, Android API 10, revision 2
  Found Google APIs, Android API 11, revision 1
  Found Google APIs, Android API 12, revision 1
  Found Google APIs, Android API 13, revision 1
  Found Google APIs, Android API 14, revision 2
  Found Google APIs, Android API 15, revision 2
  Found Google APIs, Android API 16, revision 2
  Found Google TV Addon, Android API 12, revision 2
  Found Android Support Library, revision 10
  Found Google Play Licensing Library, revision 2
  Found Google Play APK Expansion Library, revision 2
  Found Google USB Driver, revision 7
  Found Google Play Billing Library, revision 2
  Found Google AdMob Ads SDK, revision 7
  Found Google Analytics SDK, revision 2
  Found Google Web Driver, revision 2
  Found Google Cloud Messaging for Android Library, revision 3
Fetching URL: http://dl.htcdev.com/sdk/addon.xml
```

Comment: it  coming before installation, on fetching add-on.xml manifest file itself.

Comment: ok.. try restarting your eclipse and what is your internet speed?

Comment: tried this too.not working. mine is 12mbps.

Comment: try opeining http://dl.htcdev.com/sdk/addon.xml in your browser!!

Comment: it can able to see the contents in my browser. only in sdk manager, its not working.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16403/discussion-between-yokks-and-aditya-nikhade)

Comment: some weird bug with your eclipse... last would say PC restart... i think you must have done that... ill research n come up again

Answer (score 1):

- Android SDK Manager -> Tools -> Manage Add-on Sites
- Uncheck HTC, close dialog.
- Packages -> Reload.